# How to draw underline library

Tags: android

I am using a `Maven` server for deploying my libraries, [this](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).

and I can implement in `android studio`

*like this library* :
[image]

**Question** : How can I warn users I release a new version and they upgrade the version ?

*like this*

[image]


**NOTE** : I think that is automatic but it is not.

Comment: I haven't gave you that. But, in regards of the question, your maven is local?!

Comment: no that is on my server

Answer (score 0):

```
remote(HttpBuildCache) {
   url = "${artifactory_url}/gradle-cache-example/"
   credentials {
    username = "${artifactory_user}"
    password = "${artifactory_password}"
   }
   push = isPush
  }
```